# How can I use a command line parameter to access a text file?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use 3 command line parameters such as:

```
java program textfile.txt test 3
```

The first one should access a textfile, the second one should print the name, and the third one should be a numeric key that is parsed as an integer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Program
{

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException  
    {

        String textfile=null;
        String outtextfile=null;
        String enteredKey=null;
        for(String parameter: args) {
            textfile = parameter;
            outtextfile = parameter;
            enteredKey = parameter;
        }

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(textfile));

        //gets a string to encrypt
        String str = s.nextLine();

        //print outtextfile
        System.out.println(outtextfile);

        //gets a key 
        int key = Integer.parseInt(enteredKey);
```

However, that code yields this error:

```
-bash-4.1$ java Program sample.txt test 3
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 3 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
        at Program.main(Caesar.java:19)
```

Comment: You declare it in a block, and attempt to access it outside that block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a scoping problem:

The textFile variable is only visible within the for loop and is invisible outside of this loop. Are you sure that you even want to have a loop? And if so why? If the text file String is the first parameter, then get rid of the loop and only use the first parameter, args[0]:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  if (args.length == 0) {
     // exit program with an error message
  } else {
     String textFile = args[0];
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(textFile));
     // do work with Scanner
  }
```

Comment: @user2913669: **again** -- that is a separate problem and should be asked in a new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: nvm i fixed it. your solution was the correct one. i removed the for loop and used your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `textfile` in your loop, meaning it is only limited to the scope of your loop. You are trying to access it outside the loop. I would offer a suggestion, but I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String textfile=null;
for(String parameter: args) {

    textfile = parameter;
}


Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(textfile));
```

Comment: @user2913669: no it's not. Why the for loop? It makes no sense.

Comment: i updated it. could you please take a look at the new problem i'm receiving?

Comment: @user2913669: that is a separate problem and should be asked in a new question on stackoverflow.